# How to change the first element in a tuple that is a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I need to set the first element of a tuple which is a key in a dictionary to be `current`.

```
{('a', '0'): 'c',
 ('b', '0'): 'd',}
```

I need to set `'a'` as `current` variable before looping the code.
How can I do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are doing? Are you trying to use 'a' as a variable name, or just remember that the last time you checked, 'a' was valid, or what?

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the key itself because it's an immutable object. Instead, replace the dictionary key with a new one, e.g.:

```
key1, key2 = ('a', '0'), (current, 0)

d[key2] = d[key1]
del d[key1]
```

or in one step:

```
d[key2] = d.pop(key1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through all your dictionaries to update them only by the first item in your tuple key.

```
d = {('a', '0'): 'c', ('b', '0'): 'd',}

for key in d:
    new_key = key[0]
    d[new_key] = d.pop(key)

d
>>{'a': 'c', 'b': 'd'}
```

Essentially here you are deleting the old key and replacing it with a new one where you take index `0` of your tuple to be the new key.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access 'a' from the dictionary?
If you are then you can do the following:

```
list(d.keys())[0][0] 
>>> a
```

However; if the above is not what is required from you but the below is.

```
{('a', '0'): 'a', ('b', '0'): 'd'}
```

You can accomplish this with lambda or with list comprehension:

```
# Lambda
d[('a', '0')] = list(map(lambda k: k[0], d))[0]
print(d)
>>> {('a', '0'): 'a', ('b', '0'): 'd'}

# list comprehension
d[('a', '0')] = [k[0] for k in d][0]
 >>> {('a', '0'): 'a', ('b', '0'): 'd'}
```

Or are you looking to achieve something as this:

```
{('b', '0'): 'd', ('c', '0'): 'a'}
```

Again, with lambda or with list comprehension:

```
# Lambda
d[('a', '0')] = list(map(lambda k: k[0], d))[0]
d[('c', '0')] = d.pop(('a', '0'))
print(d)
>>> {('b', '0'): 'd', ('c', '0'): 'a'}

# list comprehension
d[('a', '0')] = [k[0] for k in d][0] 
d[('c', '0')] = d.pop(('a', '0'))
print(d)
>>> {('b', '0'): 'd', ('c', '0'): 'a'}
```